# XPath query matching an attribute value across two nodes

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to create an XPath query which will store an attribute value into some sort of variable at one node, then later within the same query use the value of the set variable to match on.

E.g.

A specific query would be:

```
//div[@id='1' and @name='foo']/..//input[@type='text' and @id='foo']
```

The general case would be:

```
//div[@id='1' and $var=@name]/..//input[@type='text' and @id=$var]
```

essentially I'd like to use $var as a variable which is set at one node and matched at another

Comment: XPath goal is to select nodes in a tree structure, what exactly do you want to select ? All the `input` tags that have an `id` value linked to the `name` of a `div` ? If you want to do more than selecting nodes, you may consider using an hosting langage for XPath, XQuery and XSLT may be good candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in XPath 2:

```
//div[@id='1']/for $var in @name return ..//input[@type='text' and @id=$var]
```

Or nicer in XPath 3 and also XQuery:

```
//div[@id='1']/let $var := @name return ..//input[@type='text' and @id=$var]
```